# jquery ui datepicker does not render (display) properly in IE 6.0

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a display problem with `jquery ui datepicker` in `IE 6.0`.

The border of the datepicker pop-up is not shown in IE 6.0, the background of the pop-up window is white (should be gray) and the back- and forward navigation icons are shown in a wrong color. FF and later versions of IE are showing the expected correct result.

Am I missing something really stupid here?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!
Markus

datepicker

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../30_JS/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../30_JS/ui/i18n/ui.datepicker-de.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../30_JS/jquery-ui-personalized-1.6rc4.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../00_CSS/00_jquery_theme/ui.all.css">

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#date-pick-occupied-1').datepicker({ showOn: "button",
            buttonImage: "../20_IMG/icon_date_picker.png",
            dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
            buttonImageOnly: true });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, you could take a peek at styles. Datepicker should have everything under '#ui-datepicker-div'. If you don't get a better answer, tweak the styles and add the conditional comment  and include the style.

To be completely honest, I don't even test compatibility in IE6 out of religious views, so I don't know if it plays nice in IE6. I'd try running datepicker with default settings, if it still doesn't work I'd start trimming and modifying the CSS.

Comment: Hi kRON,
I created a second answer instead of commenting your suggestion.
Please have look.
Thanks you very much in advance!